# why the text or letters entered are not displayed in alertView textfield in Iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have used a AlertView for prompting user id and password. When user clicks in user id textfield or password textfield the keyboard is popped up, thats fine. But my problem is when I try to enter text using that keyboard the letters are not showing in the textfield. IT is happening in the iphone simulator. Is there any solution. If somebody knows it please inform me. Thanx a lot.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Login" message:@"Please Enter the Following\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Sign In", nil];


//UITextField *txtUserName;
//UITextField *txtPassword;

txtUserName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 75, 160, 25)];

txtUserName.tag = 3;
txtUserName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
txtUserName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
txtUserName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
txtUserName.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
txtUserName.placeholder = @"User ID";
//txtUserName.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[alert addSubview:txtUserName]; 


txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 110, 160, 25)];
txtPassword.tag = 3;
txtPassword.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
txtPassword.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
txtPassword.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
txtPassword.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
txtPassword.placeholder = @"Password";
[alert addSubview:txtPassword];     

CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 40.0);
[alert setTransform:myTransform];   
alert.tag=3;
[alert show];
[alert release];
[txtPassword release];
[txtUserName release];
```

Comment: You have now asked 9 questions and still accepted none of the answers. Several people took their time to help you. It would be a kind gesture to "accept" those answers that helped you. It is not complicated: Just click on that checkmark outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your textcolor of each text view is WHITE, background color of each text view is also WHITE, that's why you cannot see the text.
Remove this code will solve your problem.

```
txtUserName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and

```
txtPassword.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: ohh..thanx a lot sir.....thats a big mistake....anyway how to make the password field undetectable...

Comment: just textField.secureTextEntry = YES; your text in password field will be ****, please accept the answers that solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/

Please check the above url for simplest way to make uialertview login type.

Answer (score 0):

Text Color and text background color is white..may be its the reason.Change the color and check .

Answer (score 0):

Both your label Background color and Textcolor are white So you are not able to See the text.
I have tried using your code and seen that you have not used Secure entry for your password, So here goes the code for displaying letters and Secure entry for Password.

```
.
.
txtUserName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
.
.
.
txtPassword.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
txtPassword.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[txtUserName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackcolor]];